# No matter what selection, each selection produces the same value data as the global variable

Tags: html, ajax

I'm trying to execute this and be able to get a different value for "new_id", the data is correct when getting this API call and there are 7 different id's.  However, no matter what I select produces 7 as the new_id value.  Please help, sorry for my noob question in advance!

I've tried making data[0] instead of data[i] but I really don't know where to start

```
        var new_id = "";
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
          "url":api_base+"/endpoint",
          "type":"GET",
          "contentType":"application/json",
          "success":function(data){
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select</option>';  
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  
                   s += '<option value="' + data[i].check_id + '">' + data[i].check + '</option>';  
                   new_id = data[i].check_id
               }  
               $("#check_list").html(s);
           }  
       });
```

I'd like to get a different result each time I select a different value.

Comment: try using `data.responseJSON`

Comment: sorry, the formatting cut off the global variable prior to the function line. I added it now.

Comment: @Abhyudai thank you for your response, can you be more specific?  I don't have experience at all and not sure how to try this

Comment: r u able to see different values in the drop down? also what do u need when u select the drop down value?

Comment: in your `success` function try using `data.responseJSON` instead of `data`. You can try debugging into your console by adding the line `console.log(data)` in your `complete` function

Comment: @KarthikMR yep, everything works except the final assigning of the global variable

Comment: @Abhyudai I get a js error, ',' expected when i use function(data.responseJSON)

Comment: can u do console.log(data) and copy that data and paste it here?

Comment: [{check:"yes",check_id: 1},
{check:"no",check_id: 2},
{check:"yes",check_id: 3},
{check:"yes",check_id: 4},
{check:"yes",check_id: 5},
{check:"no",check_id: 6},
{check:"yes",check_id: 7}]

Comment: your global variable will always be 7. reason -new_id variable will always override the previous check_id value in the for loop. so what is your requirement

Comment: @KarthikMR I need to be able to select "yes" in the first key value pair and return 1 as the global variable, and select "no" in the second key value pair and return 2 as the global variable (dropdown shows a list of yes yes yes yes no yes no)  sorry if doesn't make much sense, but this is my task..

Comment: you don't need global variable for it. you can do this. Add onchange function to select element and in that function you can get the value for the selected dropdown. eg - <select id="mySelect" onchange="dropDownChangeEvent()"> and function code - function dropDownChangeEvent() {
  var new_id = document.getElementById("mySelect").value; }

Comment: I'm pretty sure I do need a global variable as I need to use this value elsewhere in the code (another function) is this correct?

Comment: you can return the global variable itself, u can use this code - function dropDownChangeEvent() { new_id = document.getElementById("mySelect").value; }  so this will assign your global variable with the updated value when u select different dropdown vaiues.

Comment: @Dan Winnick did u try the above solution?

Comment: @KarthikMR can you please advise the complete solution inside my code?  not sure where to place this.  "mySelect"  is how I'm calling the select within the body?  ex. $("#check_list").html(s) from my example?

Comment: where is the code for <select></select>? So where ever the select tag is, add these attributes -  id="mySelect" onchange="dropDownChangeEvent()" and in js file add - function dropDownChangeEvent() { new_id = document.getElementById("mySelect").value; }

Comment: @Dan Winnick - The above logic will work. you can try it out.

Comment: @KarthikMR WORKED!  thank you so much and especially for your patience with me!

Comment: @Dan Winnick I glad it helped you. I have written the answer. Since the answer has helped you and as Stackoverflow community user you need to accept the answer!

Comment: Whenever you loop,it will assign last id to new_id,that'y it is giving same id each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dan Winnick - So where ever the select tag is, add these attributes - id="mySelect" onchange="dropDownChangeEvent()" and in js file add - function dropDownChangeEvent() { new_id = document.getElementById("mySelect").value; }

Comment: @Dan Winnick I glad it helped you. I have written the answer. Since the answer has helped you and and as Stackoverflow community user and policy you need to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i didnt see the answer and tried to accept from your comment.  Thank you again, awesome job!

Comment: @Dab Winnick, No problem. glad it helped. Its always a good practice to upvote the answer you found useful. So, if possible you can upvote so that it helps other users to depend on this answer.